# How to check for "0" in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 labels named `LBL1` & `LBL2` the `.text` is replaced with numbers when I pull some data from access database.

I also have 5 textboxes. In `textbox1.text` & `textbox2.text` I enter numbers(price).

the `textbox3.text` shows the (price) from `textbox1.text` without taxes.

the `textbox4.text` shows the (price) from `textbox2.text` without taxes.

And the final `textbox5.text` sums both `textbox1.text` & `textbox2.text`
I use the `.textchanged` so it calculates without pressing buttons.

Now that we have all the textboxes filled, I use a button to export the data to excel and print it. Now... everything works fine. But here is the issue.

I'm using IF statement.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LBL1.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LBL2) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text) Then
            'Excel code goes here
            'It sends all textboxes to excel in 2 rows. 
      elseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LBL1.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(LBL2) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox2.Text) then
            'Excel code goes here
            'It sends only Textbox1.text, Textbox3.text & the finaltextbox.text
      elseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LBL2.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox2.Text) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(LBL1) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text) then
        'excel code goes here
        'It sends only textbox2.text, textbox4.text & the finaltextbox.text
       else
       exit sub
end if
```

The problem lies in that if I leave a 0 in one of textbox1.text or textbox2.text, it counts it as if all textboxes are full, and sends all textboxes to excel.
In the first row its all the calculated textboxes, and the second row shows only "0".

how can I prevent that "0" be sent to excel? basically, if there is a 0 in textbox1.text or textbox2.text, it will be ignored, and only the other textbox will be sent to excel.

Thanks in advance.
It was a lengthy code so I posted only the important stuff.

Comment: Couldn't you add another condition in the if statement such as "AND textbox.text <> 0" ?

Comment: I thought that as well, but that doesn't fix my issue. If there is a "0" in one of the textboxes, the if statement doesn't launch. And nothing is sent to excel. Not even the filled textboxes.

Comment: Well yeah, thanks for the tip. It just came to me that instead of pilling all that in one IF statement I could use nested IF statements and do the textbox.text <> 0. Thanks.

Comment: There is **never** a good reason to test the contents of a `Label`. The purpose of a `Label` is to display text to the user, not to store data. Anything displayed in a `Label` has to have come from somewhere else. It's that somewhere else that you should be testing for its contents. If that somewhere else is transient then put the data into a field first and then populate the `Label` from that field, then test that field later.

Comment: I think that you probably need to brush up on your Boolean logic. You likely need to use an `Or` operator somewhere, if not everywhere. When you use `And` you are looking to match EVERY condition while `Or` matches ANY condition. Also, you should pretty much ALWAYS use `AndAlso`/`OrElse` in VB.NET rather than `And`/`Or`.

Comment: @Kohl - This is an exercise in logic. You need to logically think through all of your conditions until you get it right. You seem to possess all the knowledge you need to do this. It's just a matter of doing the exercise and getting it right. It's probably more time consuming to right this question than it would be to think slowly through the logic of what you need.

Comment: as @jmcilhinney implied you should be using OR conditions as well the best way to get through this kind of exercise do a little diagram of your conditions and where they lead